# How do you write a unit test for a regex pattern?

Tags: regex, unit-testing

Is it possible? Would it require a existing whitewashed and/or blacklisted datasets, or not? How would you know an exception did not exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you unit test regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488601/how-do-you-unit-test-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whitelists and blacklists sounds a good approach, I don't think you can "prove" it will work without exception so empirical verification is appropriate and in keeping with the spirit of unit testing

as you think up more complex/edge-case examples to test with, just add them and see if it still works, thus building a test suite in which you have ever greater levels of confidence

also, answered previously very thoroughly here

[How do you unit test regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488601/how-do-you-unit-test-regular-expressions)

Comment: **@Brian:** Thanks, that's what I thought, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: np, sometimes it's nice to get a second opinion, so FWIW I would do exactly what you're suggesting

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the following link with an identical discussion that has several good solutions:

**How do you unit test regular expressions?**
[How do you unit test regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488601/how-do-you-unit-test-regular-expressions)