# Test if a string is regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is there a good way of test if a string is a regex or normal string in PHP?

Ideally I want to write a function to run a string through, that returns true or false.

I had a look at `preg_last_error()`:

```
<?php
preg_match('/[a-z]/', 'test');
var_dump(preg_last_error());
preg_match('invalid regex', 'test');
var_dump(preg_last_error());
?>
```

Where obviously first one is not an error, and second one is. But `preg_last_error()` returns `int 0` both times.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could use a regex for the test ^^

Comment: `'invalid regex'` is a _valid_ regex - in fact, any string that doesn't involve the regex special characters will be a valid regex. Try `'['` instead.

Comment: @greg0ire: The regex specification is an irregular language. *runs*

Comment: Any normal string can be used as "regex" to do exact match. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To those that care: `'['` is not a valid regex, therefore not all strings are valid regexs.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset, `'invalid regex'` is actually not a valid regex, PHP returns `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in D:\xampp\htdocs\overheard\test.php on line 5`.

Comment: @HoshSadiq: Because the delimiters are missing. However, your code would most likely do something like `'/'.$regex.'/'`, i.e. always add the delimiters.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Except that will make a valid regex invalid.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yes, but that's the thing, I need to be able to completely check if the regex is valid, and if it's valid if I add the delimiters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only easy way to test if a regex is valid in PHP is to use it and check if a warning is thrown.

```
ini_set('track_errors', 'on');
$php_errormsg = '';
@preg_match('/[blah/', '');
if($php_errormsg) echo 'regex is invalid';
```

However, using arbitrary user input as a regex is a **bad idea**. There were security holes (buffer overflow => remote code execution) in the PCRE engine before and it might be possible to create specially crafted long regexes which require lots of cpu/memory to compile/execute.

Comment: It's not arbitrary user input, rather, rows taken from a database table that will only be added through direct code (for link generation). But yes, this worked :) Thanks!

Comment: Why is this better than just checking the output of preg_match?

Comment: `track_errors ` is deprecated as of PHP 7.2

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way to test if a string is a regex is:

```
if( preg_match("/^\/.+\/[a-z]*$/i",$regex))
```

This will tell you if a string has a good chance of being intended to be as a regex. However there are many string that would pass that check but fail being a regex. Unescaped slashes in the middle, unknown modifiers at the end, mismatched parentheses etc. could all cause problems.

The reason `preg_last_error` returned 0 is because the "invalid regex" is not:

- PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR (an internal error)
- PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR (excessively forcing backtracking)
- PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR (excessively recursing)
- PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR (badly formatted UTF-8)
- PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR (offset to the middle of a UTF-8 character)

Comment: Yes this is correct! Had this kind of figured out, just didn't know how to do it properly!
However, using `track_errors` worked!

Comment: Note also, this only works for regexes with `/` delimiters.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a good answer how to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941133/2519073

```php
if(@preg_match($your_pattern, '') === false){
    //pattern is broken
}else{
    //pattern is real
}
```

Comment: Better solutions the rest 2, as `track_errors` is deprecated with PHP 7.2

Comment: Only one suggestion - the 2nd parameter should be a string (e.g. an empty string). In newer PHP versions that would cause a deprecation error (although the `@` mutes it anyway, but I wouldn't rely on it): https://3v4l.org/5YI6t

Answer (score 9):

Why not just use...another regex?  Three lines, no `@` kludges or anything:

```
// Test this string
$str = "/^[A-Za-z ]+$/";

// Compare it to a regex pattern that simulates any regex
$regex = "/^\/[\s\S]+\/$/";

// Will it blend?
echo (preg_match($regex, $str) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

Or, in function form, even more pretty:

```
public static function isRegex($str0) {
    $regex = "/^\/[\s\S]+\/$/";
    return preg_match($regex, $str0);
}
```

---

This doesn't test validity; but it looks like the question is `Is there a good way of test if a string is a regex or normal string in PHP?` and it does do that.

Comment: I presume it's because you can't detect all regexes with a regex - the best this can do is decide whether it looks *kinda like* a regex or not.

Comment: For the regex-lovers, the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression) might be interesting...

Comment: Does not work with flags? Sample '/(\n)}[\s\n\r]*$/s'

Comment: this answer does not support modifiers

Comment: ..nor does it support any other delimiter than `/`. E.g. ``#/some/path/#` is a valid regex using hash marks, which is very common when matching paths. And since it's using regex matching anyway, might as well go with the false-return approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since regex must be always surrounded only with one of three boundary characters `/`, `@`, `#`, and trailing characters may only be allowed [modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), we can use quick test:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\/@#](.+)[\/@#imsxADSUXJun]+$/', $pattern, $match) ){
   // .. do stuff, $match[0] contains full regex
}
```

This does not guarantee proper REGEX syntax in any way, but helps with quick detection.