# Most efficient way to check if a string in PHP is a valid regular expression

Tags: php, regex, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression)
>   [Test if a string is regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778318/test-if-a-string-is-regex)

Given a string, I have a case where I want to be able to check if it is a regular expression. So far, the best approach I have is this:

```
<?php

function validate_regex($str){
    return preg_match($str, "anything here") !== false;
}
```

Is there a better way to check this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php ?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778318/test-if-a-string-is-regex

Comment: Also check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Comment: Thanks! I guess a separate question would be whether or not setting track_errors would cause a significant performance hit / other issues.