# How to unit test regular expressions when samples are in a file?

Tags: unit-testing, grep, tdd

Here in a file (test.txt) which keep sample text to match.

Here is the sample text.

```
evince /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/kids/Coping Skills.pdf
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --impress file:///home/ismail/Desktop/LibreOffice%20Impress.odp --splash-pipe=5
/usr/bin/gjs /usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/kids/Coping Skills.epub
mpv /media/ismail/8TBRaid0/_IslamNaseed/_JunaidJamshed/Mera Dil Badal De.mp3
evince /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/self-development-anxiety-self-talk/child/Freeing Your Child From Negative Thinking Powerful, Practical Strategies to Build a Lifetime of Resilience, Flexibility, and... (Tamar E. Chansky) My Library).pdf --splash-pipe=5
This is the line that does not match.
/usr/bin/gjs /usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/self-development-anxiety-self-talk/child/Freeing Your Child from Anxiety Powerful, Practical Solutions to Overcome Your Childs Fears, Worries, and Phobias (Tamar Chansky Ph.D.) (My Library).epub
```

Here is the regex that give **lines that did not match** in test.txt

```
grep -nvP '(file://)?(?<!\w)/(?!usr/).*?\.\w{3,4}+' test.txt
```

I want to create a unit test which will fail if all the lines in this file does not match. I also want to know which line did not match. In the given grep command it gives the line numbers (`-n`) so I have to manually check if a line is missing.

The idea is I will add new lines to the file as we progress and run the test.

I have checked [How do you unit test regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488601/how-do-you-unit-test-regular-expressions) but it does not talk about this approach. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements properly and `bash` is available
as a wrapper script, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(wc -l < test.txt)
failed=$(grep -nvP '(file://)?(?<!\w)/(?!usr/).*?\.\w{3,4}+' test.txt | sed 's/:.*//')
failed_lines=$(wc -l <<< "$failed")

if (( lines == failed_lines )); then
    echo "all lines did not match"
fi

echo "failed lines are:" $(tr "\n" " " <<< "$failed")
```

- The variable `lines` counts the lines in `test.txt`.
- The variable `failed` stores the line numbers which did not match.
- The variable `failed_lines` counts the lines of `failed`.
- If `lines` and `failed_lines` are the same, it means the all lines did not match. Then report on it.
- Finally report the line numbers which did not match.